# Rails yield is called multiple times when multiple partials are rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, render, partial-views, yield

I have multiple partials that I'm rendering, the idea being that the partials render in a row, and there's a different bit of content. So for the output like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" data-page='1'>
    <h1>Page 1 Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row" data-page='2'>
    <h1>Page 2 Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row" data-page='3'>
    <h1>Page 3 Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am writing a code like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <% (1..3).each do |p| %>
    <div class="row" data-page="<%= p %>"> 
      <%= render "partials/o#{p}" %>
      <h1><%= yield :title %></h1>
    </div> 
  <% end %>
</div>

<!-- o1 partial -->
<% content_for :title do %>
   Page 1 Title
<% end %>

<!-- o2 partial -->
<% content_for :title do %>
   Page 2 Title
<% end %>

<!-- o3 partial -->
<% content_for :title do %>
   Page 3 Title
<% end %>
```

The problem with the above code is that on page 2 and page 3, it has contents from the previous pages as well. Like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" data-page='1'>
    <h1>Page 1 Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row" data-page='2'>
    <h1>Page 1 Title
      Page 2 Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row" data-page='3'>
    <h1>Page 1 Title
      Page 2 Title
      Page 3 Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I avoid this and get back to the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have completely misunderstood how the [captures helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html) works.

Each `yield` block essentially waits for the entire view to finish rendering so that its sure that all content has been provided. You can think of each named yield as a buffer. In your case even if you have multiple calls to yield they all point to the `:title` buffer.

`content_for` writes content to the buffer when called with 2+ arguments (`content_for(:foo, 'bar')` or outputs the buffer when called with one argument. Note that `content_for` concatenates the content by design:

```
<%= yield :poem %>
<% content_for :poem, "Roses are red" %>
<% content_for :poem, " violets are blue" %>
# => "Roses are red violets are blue"
```

This can be altered by using the `flush: true` option which replaces anything previously captured.

```
<%= yield :poem %>
<% content_for :poem, "This gets flushed..." %>
<% content_for :poem, "Roses are red violets are blue", flush: true %>
# => "Roses are red violets are blue"
```

You can also use [`provide`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-provide) which streams straight into yield block.

But for this case I would wonder if your not just using it improperly where a simple local variable would do the job with less hackyness.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your partials with flush mention :

```
<!-- o1 partial -->
<% content_for :title, flush: true do %>
   Page 1 Title
<% end %>

<!-- o2 partial -->
<% content_for :title, flush: true do %>
   Page 2 Title
<% end %>

<!-- o3 partial -->
<% content_for :title, flush: true do %>
   Page 3 Title
<% end %>
```